# What is the correct adjective for weight/mass of objects, heavy or large?

Tags: adjectives

The mass of an object is defined as the "amount of "matter" in an object, whereas weight is the force exerted on an object by gravity".

However, I often see in scientific literature the adjective "large" associated to mass/weight, such as "this animal is larger than another", or "small animals". Is this correct or would "heavier" be the correct adjective to use?

Mind you that volume is never discussed in these texts, they always discuss mass/weight in Kg. This trend can be observed in top scientific journals such as Science or Nature, so what would be considered the most authoritative scientific references.

Maybe this applies also to other contexts.

EDIT: I am not interesting in discussing the difference between mass and weight. I am wondering why authors are using "large animal" when there's no volume or size involved, instead they mean "heavy animal".

Comment: An ***ostrich***, for example, is a bird. Which presumably means it has lighter bones than, say, mammals. Plus much of the "size" of an ostrich is accounted for by stereotypically  lightweight ***feathers***. So I'm sure there must be mammals that are ***heavier, but not so large as*** ostriches. Mass, volume, size, and weight are conceptually different.

Comment: I guess that you mean heavy, or massive, as mass X gravity, or just plain old mass, respectively.  In which case, simplistically speaking, it's the gravitational field intermediates between the two.  This is the distinction between gravity, and gravitation.  So, without further delving into what, exactly, is the connection from neither the mass nor the gravity side of things per se, I would, somewhat incorrectly, say, gravitational objects.

Comment: If all you wanted to know was ***Which of [heavy mammals, large mammals](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+heavy+mammals%2Cof+large+mammals&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20large%20mammals%3B%2Cc0) is more common?***, you could have done that same search as me on Google NGrams. I'm afraid I think this question is just Too Basic for ELU.

Comment: _Large_ and _small_ are relative terms. Mercury is a small planet, but its mass is much more than that of the largest mammal. It depends on what you're describing, and what the presupposed norm in context is. So you won't find them as measurements (except comparatively) in scientific publications, where  mass and weight are normally distinguished and measured in appropriate units.

Comment: How then to come up with a single positive number for each object that reflects all of the above, etc, "apples and oranges" aspects averaged out?

Comment: 'Higher' or 'greater' mass; 'greater' weight. The absolute forms are similar.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's exactly what I don't understand! Saying "large mammal" doesn't make any sense because it implies volume or perhaps size. But 95% of authors use large as a proxy for weight.

Comment: @JohnLawler I do agree with you, but for planets using large/small makes sense when discussing their size. But when discussing their mass you would use heavier or lighter, or greater mass. But since the most common measurement in animals is mass and not volume or size, for me using large seems contradictory.

Comment: No, you wouldn't use "heavy" or "light" for a planet. Those refer to what things and people weigh on a planet, normally ours. A _heavy planet_ means a planet with a high G force where people would weigh more than 1 G. In general, natural language terms (which evolved long before physics) refer to mass in a 1 G field, and size relative to a human scale.

Comment: Why the heck not a heavy versus light planet?  For example, planets orbit their suns, so, they find orbits appropriate to their weight, speed, etc, and, distance from their suns. https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/planets-weight/en/

Comment: The weight(force) of one kg is equal to one kgf, or 9.8N.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/138293/why-do-we-use-kilograms-instead-of-newtons-to-measure-weight-in-everyday-life

Answer (score 1):

> I often see in scientific literature the adjective "large" associated
> to mass/weight, such as "this animal is larger than another"

Are you sure this is what you see? I would be surprised. The default meaning for "large" when it comes to animals and most physical objects refers to overall volume (of the envelope), not to mass/weight. Of course a high volume object is often heavier than a small object but this is not inevitable.

In the following fanciful image, the balloon is larger than the elephant, even though we know that the elephant is heavier/more massive.

---

***envelope** = a surface that surrounds the shape.

[image]

Comment: Not a good example to reflect your position that, "a high volume object is often heavier than a small object but this is not inevitable".  Going skyward, the balloon is "heavier".

Comment: Yes I am quite sure because I read these articles all the time. Any of these articles https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=us&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=large+mammals&btnG= use "large mammals" to identify mammals weighting over X amount of Kg. They never use volume measurement because measuring volume in animals is rather complex. Nor they use size measurements such head to toe length.

Comment: @Herman Toothrot - I can see that those articles refer to large animals but I don't see where it says that large = heavy. Can you give an actual definition of large in one of these? If not, then I continue to say that "large" refers to spatial dimensions and not mass.   I understand that the approximate density of animals tends to be similar and therefore, in general, larger animals *are* heavier but that doesn't mean that these quantities are the same.

Comment: @Rem - "*Going skyward, the balloon is 'heavier'*"(?)  I have no idea what that means. In relation to the atmosphere, an elephant is heavier than air and a helium balloon is lighter (not heavier) than air.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Look at this one https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/1/4/e1400103?con=&dom=prime&src=syndication "Large wild herbivores are crucial to ecosystems and human societies. We highlight the 74 largest terrestrial herbivore species on Earth (body mass ≥100 kg)". This is in Science. I think this use of large is simply wrong but it's widespread.

Comment: @Herman Toothrot - Actually I'm happy with that example because they are in effect *defining* what they mean by large. As long as scientists define their terms I don't have any problems with them.

Comment: The balloon lifts the elephant.  Lifting (upward) involves force upward, whereas gravity (downward) involves force downward.  In this case, in order to provide more force upward on the elephant than is, already, downward, the balloon must be quite a bit larger than the elephant.  A smaller balloon won't work.  The purpose of your example seems to be to show that something with less mass may be larger, which is true of the (larger) balloon, but not in the sense of its force on the elephant.  In the sense you applied the word, larger.

Comment: @Rem - I had no intention of implying that a balloon that size would lift an elephant - it wouldn't. I just grabbed that picture from Google images because it had elephants and balloons in the same frame. I *could* have spent half an hour photo-shopping a real balloon into a photo of a herd of elephants but I didn't want to.

Comment: Sigh............

Answer (score 0):

> large (adjective)
>
> big in size or amount
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/large)

Hence we may speak of a balloon as *large* (in size) but *small* (in mass of membrane and gas). Or we may speak of a sandbag that is *small* in size but *large* in mass of sand.

A simple statement that something is *large* merely says that it is *large in size*. It says nothing about *mass*. In your example of animals, there is a general correlation between the *mass* and volume (*size*) of land animals or fish, so sloppy usage may well say the animal is *large*, implying that its *mass* is also large. But this is careless and vague unless the context already clearly relates to *mass*.

In scientific writing it is bad practice to use the words *large* or *small* alone when talking about anything other than *size*. Such careless use of terms might pass in popular writing on science but should be edited out in anything authoritative. When taking about *mass*, say *large mass* or *small mass*.

Also, in scientific writing it is important to distinguish between *mass* and *weight*. A mass of a kilogram weighs a kilogram in earth's gravity but weighs nothing in space.

Comment: I do agree with you but as I have mentioned anywhere in the scientific literature I find the use of "large" or "very large" as a proxy for weight. Look at this https://scholar.google.it/scholar?hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=large+mammals&btnG= . Why do you associate the concept of mass with large? For me a mass is heavy or light. Mass is measured in Kg so why would you use large/small? You don't say my backpack is large when you want to say that it's actually heavy. Large I would use it to indicate volume.

Comment: You ask why speak of large mass? Why not? According to the dictionary definitions (and to my own experience), the adjective *large* applies to many things: volumes; lengths; intellects; bones; areas; mammals; faunas &  extent (all as in the link you give); dresses, shirts ... so why not apply it mass? The units of mass or any other qualified noun are irrelevant: a mass of 10 kg is larger than that of 1 kg whether you measure the mass in kg, tonnes, ounces or milligrams. And I do say "large rucksack", as is shown in google ngram. If the sack is full it may be heavy; if empty it is light.

Answer (score -1):

> The mass of an object is defined as the "amount of matter" in an
> object

Defining mass as "amount of matter" is garbage that is passed for science in middle school. Mass is measure of body's inertia. It is resistance to changing its velocity when a net force is applied.

Mass is measured in kilograms (in SI). Amount of matter is measured in moles (mol).

We can talk about heavy and light bodies as difference in their change of velocity under the same force. Bodies placed on Earth's surface experience the same gravitational pull, so equality of masses means equality of weights. Hence, I don't see any problem talking about "heavy" and "light" in regards to mass. Obviously, "large" does not mean "large mass", it just means large dimensions. Thus, "heavy" == "large mass".